# how to give DTO to LINQ select many query in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

How to give DTO to select or SelectMany

```
public class PersonDTO
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string UserName { get; set; }
                public string Email { get; set; }
            }

var person = _context.Persons.Where(x=>x.PersonId==1).SelectMany(PersonDTO);
```

I want to build a service that I give model or DTO and it returns only those raws that are given in the model or DTO but only from the person table or user detail table

which means something like graphql that get data by DTO, and DTO could be Only Name or UserName or Email or all of them, any Idea?

Comment: You'll need some way to map them into the dto (copy constructor, manually, etc.) and based on what I see, you need Select not SelectMany.

Comment: is this work? _context.Persons.Where(x => x.PersonId == 1).Select(x => typeof(PersonDTO));

Comment: What Chief says: You don't need to flatten the structure, so just use Select or depending on how you want to move on maybe even simply `.ToList`. And then you may want to consider some Mapper libs, too? Like AutoMapper or Mapster, ...

Comment: Does the Entity have the exact same properties as the DTO?

Comment: `_context.Persons.Where(x=>x.PersonId==1).Select(p => new PersonDTO { Id = p.PersonId, /* etc */ }).FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_context.Persons.Where(x => x.PersonId == 1).Select(x => typeof(PersonDTO));` won't automagically map your type.

What you probably want is something like this, when doing it "manually":

```
_context.Persons
           .Where(x => x.PersonId == 1)
           .Select(x => new PersonDto(){
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                UserName = x.UserName,
                Email = x.Email
            });
```

Comment: I'm trying to make something like graphql that get data by DTO, which means DTO could be Only Name or UserName or Email or all of them, any Idea?

Comment: @regestea23 It sounds like you want to return a potentially dynamic object from the data set. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly, I want to build a service that I give model or DTO and it returns only those raws that are given in the model or DTO but only from the person table or user detail table

Comment: Can you add an example to the question? That sounds like you'll need reflection, I am afraid. Or the help of a Mapper lib...

Comment: I'm trying to do that graphql  do but only with LINQ